# Attempting to combine data but appears to stall

Tags: powershell, office365

I make use of a script that grabs licensing information which works fine. I wanted to grab group information into this script so I can see what groups a person is in while also getting other information on them, the important part of the script looks as the follows

```
$result = foreach($domain in $domains){
    $users = Get-MsolUser -all | where {$_.islicensed -eq "$true" -and $_.Userprincipalname -match "$domain"}
        foreach ($i in $users){
        
        $licenses = $i.Licenses
        $licenseArray = $licenses | foreach-Object {$_.AccountSkuId}
        $licensear = Friendlyname
        $licenseString = $licenseAr -join ", "
                    
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{

        Displayname = $i.Displayname
        Userprincipalname = $i.userprincipalname
        UPN = ($i.userprincipalname -Split '@')[1]
        Licenses = $licenseString

        }
    }
}
```

This works without issues but obviously, it isn't possible to grab group information from `Get-MsolUser` which led me to make use of `Get-MsolGroup` to keep in use of MSonline module. As such I've added the following:

```
$Groups1 = foreach ($Group in (Get-MsolGroup -all)){ 
                   if (Get-MsolGroupMember -all -GroupObjectId $Group.ObjectId | where {$_.Emailaddress -eq $i.UserPrincipalName}) {$Group.Displayname}
           }

$groups2 = $Groups1 -join ", "
```

in combination, I've added this to be fed into the new-object area with `Groups = $groups2`

What I'm running into here is a massive stall where nothing is actually being done, when testing this via the debugger I can see that $groups1/2 is grabbing and outputting as I'd expect but it seems to stall at the line I've added.

What I'm expecting to happen is it to complete so that when I select-object against these new objects the groups field will be populated with $groups2 data, this is not happening.

What exactly could be causing this behavior?

Comment: for every user you are listing all group members of every group, that's going to take forever and probably causing you to be throttled. I would collect all groups/members prior to your user loop then just reference the variable containing these groups/members .

Comment: @DougMaurer I assumed that would be the case but breaking/debugged $results is returning nothing when I'm testing, I don't mind this taking a number of hours as it's a 1 off but I'm curious if what I'm doing has a fundamental flaw which wouldn't work that i'm overlooking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, I'd gather the groups and members first, then just reference that variable in your user loop.

```
$groups = Get-MsolGroup -All

$groupsandmembers = $groups | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        GroupName = $_.displayname
        Members   = Get-MsolGroupMember -All -GroupObjectId $_.objectid |
                        Select-Object -ExpandProperty emailaddress
    }
}

$result = foreach($domain in $domains){
    $users = Get-MsolUser -all | Where-Object {
        $_.islicensed -eq $true -and
        $_.Userprincipalname -match $domain
    }

    foreach ($i in $users){
    
        $licenses = $i.Licenses
        $licenseArray = $licenses.AccountSkuId
        $licensear = Friendlyname
        $licenseString = $licenseAr -join ", "
                
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Displayname       = $i.Displayname
            Userprincipalname = $i.userprincipalname
            UPN               = ($i.userprincipalname -Split '@')[1]
            Licenses          = $licenseString
            Groups            = ($groupsandmembers | Where-Object members -contains $i.userprincipalname).groupname -join ', '
        }
    }
}
```